# Prepare dataset for the LDA topic models using CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling, countvectorizer

I want to use `CountVectorizer`from `Scikit`to create a matrix that to be used by `LDA` model. But my dataset is a sequence of coded terms, for example in the following form:

```
(1-2252, 5-5588, 10-5478, 2-9632 ....)
```

How can I tell the `CountVectorizer` to consider each pair of data i.e. `1-2252` as one word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I found a [helpful](https://blog.mafr.de/2012/04/15/scikit-learn-feature-extractio/) blog that gave me the answer.

As I used the following method to tokenize the text:

```
import re
REGEX = re.compile(r",\s*")
def tokenize(text):
    return [tok.strip().lower() for tok in REGEX.split(text)]
```

And pass the tokenizer to the `CountVectorizer` as follows:

```
tf = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)
```